# How to take screen video on ubuntu 10.04 and above

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu and I need to prepare a video from it. Is any ubuntu software for that ?

Voice from end user should be also taken.

Comment: Try posting in askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below command**

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-recordmydesktop
```

Comment: You might also like to use screenkey at the same time to show keyboard usage.